# Retrofit gives connection timeout while uploading image using wifi with static ip address

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-networking

I am using retrofit for image uploading and posting image using Content-Type: multipart/form-data

But the problem is that when I am connected with wifi using static ip address, it gives connection socket timeout error like :

```
HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

It works fine with other network conditions like LAN, mobile data and wifi with non static ip address.

Comment: Please give more info. Also try checking the same or similar url in browser and let us know what is the readings...

Comment: Working well in browser, as expected.

Comment: the same server are you using for wifi and lan?